# Java, My numbers getting printed rounded down

Tags: java, arraylist

My `setAverage` method is getting a list of numbers to sum them up. If I give an `ArrayList` of lets say `200 200 200`, the outcome is `600`. But if I give it `200 200 250`, the coutome is the same. I do not get it.
Also: I do not want to get the average now, I am at the point of just sum up the array.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class calculation {

    private ArrayList<Integer> x;
    private int z;  

    public void setAverage(ArrayList<Integer> myList) {
        x = myList;
        for(int i: myList) {
            z += i;
            break;
        }                               
    }
    public int getAverage() {
        return z;   
    }   
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class eingaben {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        calculation rechneAVG = new calculation();
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();


            while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
                myList.add(scan.nextInt());
                rechneAVG.setAverage(myList);
            }


        System.out.println(rechneAVG.getAverage());

    }

}
```

Comment: You only get the first element, not calculate the average.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. At the very least, that `break` is wrong, but it's hard to see how that relates to your question, since you wouldn't get 600 with that.

Comment: That break inside for loop is making the for loop end always after one single iteration. In order words, code inside for only executes once.

Comment: Also, z needs to be initialized before being added values

Comment: `x.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).average().orElseThrow()`

Comment: Why do you call it average? It is the Sum. If you want the average your getAverage method should also devide the sum with total numbers (e.g. return z/x.size(); )

Answer (score 0):

Typically you're not looking to use a break statement in a foreach style loop, the break will terminate the loop which is what is causing your issues here.

Also I'm not a big fan of what you're doing with the setting of x to the value of the input list. Could you maybe restructure the function to return a value that is added to your list? Not really part of your question, more of an aside.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing something like this before

```java
ArrayList<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(new int[] {200,200,250});
calculation calc = new calculation();
calc.setAverage(list);
```

Then you should rewrite your class like this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculation {

    private ArrayList<Integer> intList;
    private int avg;  

    public void setAverage(ArrayList<Integer> myList) {
        intList = myList;
        avg = 0;
        for(int i: myList) {
            avg += i;
        }                               
    }
    public int getAverage() {
        return avg;   
    }   
}
```

That is: initialize `z` (I renamed it to `avg`) and ditch the `break;`

Also, never use break. I am fighting my own crusade to stop coders from using break/continue, but they tell me I'm crazy.